# ASP.Net CrystalReportViewer just rendering vertical lines

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a plain asp.Net page that contains a CrystalReportViewer.  I use the following code to in the Page_Load method to display a report:

```
ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
                    TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
                    TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
                    ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
                    Tables CrTables;

                    report.Load(Server.MapPath("Reports\\" + Request.Params[0]));

                    crConnectionInfo.ServerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportSQLServer"];
                    crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportSQLDatabase"];
                    crConnectionInfo.UserID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportSQLUsername"];
                    crConnectionInfo.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportSQLPassword"];

                    CrTables = report.Database.Tables;
                    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
                    {
                        crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
                        crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                        CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
                    }

                    Session["Report"] = report;
                    rptViewer.ReportSource = report;
                    rptViewer.RefreshReport();
```

However, no matter what report I load, it displays as follows:

[image: This is how it displays]

When I use the exact same logic in a WinForms app to populate a CrystalReportsViewer there, the report displays as expected.

Please advise as to what I am missing in the asp.net web form to make the report display correctly.

Comment: Do you solution for this issue? I am facing exact problem.

Comment: Hi I got solution, It is displaying stripes to IE10 browser mode, If browser mode switch to "IE10 Compatibility mode", everything is working fine.

Comment: post this as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have same issue in IE10,Vertical stripes are displaying instead of data in reportviewer in IE10 browser mode.

Solution is to switch **"IE10 Compatibility mode",** everything is working fine

Comment: Has crystal addressed this? We are not allowed to force the users to change compatibility mode. This is a deal breaker in our case.

Answer (score 1):

Try Setting
HasDrilldownTabs="False"
example

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1"
                        HasDrilldownTabs="False"/>
```

Same is working in my case
 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, append `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">` in the head section of the page.